# Why do all my apps on my Mac show the .app at the end when they normally don't?

Tags: mac, finder

I noticed last month that my apps looked different in the Finder. Shrugged it off for a bit, now it's a bit annoying. How do I change it back to it's original state of not showing the file extension (.app)?

[This is what it looks like currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJG02.png)

Comment: Did you perhaps enable in Finder that it should show all file extensions?

Comment: ok yea that worked. put it as an answer so I can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Finder, you can enable an option to always show file extensions:

[image: Finder Advanced Options]

If enabled, this also affects other places where apps are listed, like Spotlight.

Try disabling that option.